# Meteor: Difference between Subscribe and Data

Tags: routes, meteor, publish-subscribe, iron-router

Using Iron  Router, I want to access specific data depending on the page the user is on. [This](http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/iron-router-tutorial) tutorial uses a function of Iron Router called "data" which provides data depending on what page the user is on. But there is also another method using waitOn and subscribing.

What exactly is the difference between those methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's analyze simple case from tutorial you mentioned:

Client Side:

```
this.route('authors', {
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('authorList');
  },
  data: function () {
    return { authors: Authors.find() };
  }
});
```

Server Side (that part I have added myself):

```
Meteor.publish("authorList", function () {
  return Authors.find();
});
```

Assuming that `Authors` collection has 3 authors:

```
[{name:"Allan"},{name:"Brian"},{"name":"Joe"}]
```

Just to make it very simple I assume that server side publishes all authors in `authorList` publish function.

#### Explanation

In `waitOn` you return subscription `authorList`. That gives us 2 benefits:

1) Client Side subscribes to `authorList`, so all 3 documents from collection `Authors` will be send via DDP to Client Side.

2) IronRouter can display `loadingTemplate` until all data is received.

In `data` function you can return :

- whole set (3 authors):

  `Authors.find();`
- or subset (1 or 2 authors):

  `// one author:
  Authors.find({name:"Allan"});`

  of subscribed data.

If there is no subscription then `Authors.find()` will not be populated with data.

Hope that helps.
Just in case it is not clear, I recommend to read : https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/understanding-meteor-publications-and-subscriptions/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that already helps a lot. I have read the article you recommended but I'm still not so sure what the data-property does and whether or not it is necessary to subscribe to a collection before using  it for data.

Comment: Remove package `autopublish` by executing : `mrt remove autopublish`, then don't subscribe in `waitOn` and then try to exectute `Authors.find()` in `data`. You will not receive any data, as they are not send to client with subscription.

Answer (score 0):

'data' sets the context of the template being rendered.  Handlebars lets you read properties from the context like this - {{ someProperty }}.

'subscribe' requests new collection data for the client from the server.